Google Maps in my flutter using package google_maps_flutter it show in ios simulator but it's not show on an actual ios device(my iphone)
i implemented google maps in my flutter application using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter. it's shown in an android emulator but it's not shown on an ios simulator and an actual ios device(my iphone)

pubspec.yaml:
google_maps_flutter: ^2.6.1

AppDelegate.swift:
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-9I")
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}


Podfile

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end


info.plist

<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Access location for find nearby store</string><key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Access location for find nearby store</string><key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Access location for find nearby store</string><key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Access location for find nearby store</string><key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>

solved this problem shown in my device (iphone)
